# Convert FormCollection to object of type known only at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I have controller with action containing code, which looks like

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection data)
{
    var type = findTypeByName(data["CastToTypeName"]);
    var model = transformRequestDataToType(data/* or may be Request*/, type) as DbEntity;
    SaveData(model);
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to transform request data to object of runtime-known type?
I post data to controller with `<form>` and trying to find solution without changing form data to json.

Comment: That looks dangerous. Quite a handy way for (nefarious) users to modify any DB data they want.

Comment: This is in admin part of a small site, so am just block any such posibilities by adding auth for the controller.

Comment: Looks to me that you are forgetting to force form classes to implement an interface.  Pretty crucial if you want MVC to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I simplified input names notation to such as:

```
a.name
a.items\
a.items/name
a.items/desc
a.items\
a.items/name
a.items/desc
```

was

```
a.name
a.items.Index
a.items[0].name
a.items[0].desc
a.items.Index
a.items[1].name
a.items[1].desc
```

next I extract form data before submit using js, prevent form submit and send ajax post request with the form data to url defined in `action` form attribute. On server side I parse data and recursively assign it to properties of instance of given type. So I can `ParseAs<MyType>(Request)` or even `ParseAsGiven(Request)` when `CastToTypeName` value is set.